SciPy TRF: motivation for changing update_tr_radius argument
After upgrading the SciPy version I've observed deterioration of the curve fitting quality for some data. I've investigated this problem and found that changing the update_tr_radius argument causes this problem. In commit update_tr_radius argument was changed: commit diff
I have run tests for multiple datasets and for most of them the result is the same, for some cases it is worse. Could someone explain how the correction value influences the result and why this modification could have been introduced?
